# Setting up AWS access keys in ReadTheDocs account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, key, read-the-docs

I'm trying to download some files from S3 bucket as part of `jobs.pre_build` in `.readthedocs.yaml` file. This is specifically needed for every pull request created. For this to work we need to setup the IAM user's access keys in the environment variables in ReadtheDocs advanced settings of the project.

Mentioning here a code snippet.

```
jobs:
    pre_build:
      - pip install awscli
      - aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${aws_access_key_id}
      - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${aws_secret_access_key}
      - aws s3 cp s3://some_path some_file
```

Here `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` are configured as environment variables in Readthedocs.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/environment-variables.html), `Check the Public option if you want to expose this environment variable to builds from pull requests`. However, we don't want to expose AWS access keys as public. Is there any other approach to setup these keys without exposing them?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question.

### This problem is universal for all CIs

When doing a Pull Request build, you are allowing essentially others to build their version of your project on your CI setup.

Usually this is great: If a user changes something in the documentation, they can have their branch built with their changes, generating for instance an online preview.

But someone could also pass by and put anything else into your build since it's essentially just a bunch of code that is executing in a Docker container. They can overwrite anything originating from your git repository, including Python dependencies, scripts and adding commands in `.readthedocs.yaml`.

Usually, this does not cause any vulnerability since builds do not contain secrets and build environments are isolated. The worst thing that can happen is a waste of computing resources.

### Can we use secret environment variables in Pull Requests?

Short answer: No, it's not possible.

An environment variable exposed in Pull Request builds cannot be maintained as a "secret".

It's very easy to add "echo $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE" somewhere and it's also very easy to obtain knowledge of the name of the variable by reading the .readthedocs.yaml file.

Let's pretend that you could make the keys secret: Then the downloaded files would *still* be exposed to the PR build. So an attacker could open a PR and upload the files somewhere.

### Workarounds?

Supposing that the files are **insensitive**: I would suggest that *if* you are able to generate an AWS access key that can only download these files, then obtaining access to the environment variable would render access to exactly the same files as are intended to be downloaded and readable inside the build. The AWS access key would only give access to the same files that are already used in the build, so obtaining access to the key doesn't achieve anything. But you can see the key as a good hindrance for wider access to large data sets and you can rotate the key once in a while.

Supposing that the files are **sensitive**: In this case, I would not recommend that you give PR builds access to the files themselves. This actually transforms the problem away from the environment variables!

You could perhaps give PR builds access to a set of test data?

Example: Run a pre_build.sh script from your `.readthedocs.yaml`.

.readthedocs.yaml:

```
jobs:
    pre_build:
      - sh -c pre_build.sh
```

pre_build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ["$READTHEDOCS_VERSION_TYPE" = "external"]
then
    # Download some dummy data that's insensitive for PR builds
    curl https://testdata.com/test.csv
else
    pip install awscli
    # These were from your original script, but they are insecure
    # Use instead: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html
    # aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${aws_access_key_id}
    # aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${aws_secret_access_key}
    aws s3 cp s3://some_path some_filefi
```

### ⚠️ Strong warning about environment variables in general ⚠️

Running a command like `aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${aws_access_key_id}` will make the environment variable become part of the command that is executing - and that becomes part of a log file and process monitoring.

**This essentially leaks the secret!**

There are a lot of small tips and tricks out there to pass environment variables to commands, but it's always a bit of a hassle. But I think the aws CLI have you covered, so you just need to give the variables the expected names: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html